# Data Modeling: Is it bad practice to store IDs from various sources in the same column?

Tags: sql-server, data-modeling

I am attempting to merge data from various sources into an existing data model. Each source uses different types of IDs (such as GUID, Salesforce IDs, etc.). For example, if I were to merge data from two different sources, the table may look like the following (where the first two SalesPersonIDs are GUID IDs and the second two are Salesforce IDs):

[image: Example]

Is this a bad practice? I could also imagine a table where each ID type was its own column and could be left blank if it was not applicable. Something like the following:

[image]

I apologize, I am a bit new to this. Thanks in advance for any insight, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: If IDs come from different [external] sources how would you deal with collisions? Maybe a composite key (source_id, id) could resolve the situation.

Answer (score 0):

The big roles of an ID column are to act as a key connecting data in different tables, and to help indexing - quickly find rows so your queries run fast.

The second solution wouldn't work well for these purposes, and will lead to big headaches in queries: every time you want to group by the ID, you'll have to combine the info from 2 columns in some way, hopefully getting a correct unique result every time.

On the one hand, all you might ever need from an ID is for it to be unique. The first solution might be fine this respect - but are you sure you'll never, ever get data about one SalesPerson from more than one source?

I'd suggest keeping all the IDs in one column, and adding a column to say what kind of ID this is. At least this way, you won't lose any information and can do other things in the future.

One thing you might consider is making a separate table of SalesPerson with all their possible IDs, and have this keyed to other (Sales?) data by a unique ID used only in your database.

Comment: You don't mention the main driving force, referential integrity. That can only be guaranteed by the second alternative. Also, indexes can be filtered on nut null values and queries will probably never want to get IDs from both columns. Adding a column for "kind of ID" is known as a polymorphic associations anti pattern.

Comment: The main role of primary key is to ensure uniqueness, not speed.

Comment: A bigger problem is the data type - mixing GUID and integers means you cannot use either data type for the column.  The best you could do in that scenario would be to use a sql_variant data type - which is not a good idea for a primary key or clustered index.